# VS Code keeps stopping for __enter__ problem, but I don't know how to fix it

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

First of all, my English is not very accurate so, sorry if I'm not very descriptive.

I have troubles to resolve a problem in VS Code. First of all, magicaly, Pylance had problems with psycopg2, and it solved itself... Thats not the problem but to fill the history.

The problem is with `with` in this code:

```
from conexion import Conexion
from persona import Persona
from logger_base import log

class PersonaDao:
    _SELECCIONAR = 'SELECT * FROM personas ORDER BY id_persona'
    _INSERTAR = 'INSERT INTO personas(nombre, apellido, correo) VALUES(%s, %s, %s)'
    _ACTUALIZAR = 'UPDATE personas SET nombre=%s, apellido=%s, correo=%s WHERE id_persona=%s'
    _ELIMINAR = 'DELETE FROM personas WHERE id_persona=%s'

    @classmethod
    def seleccionar(cls):
        with Conexion.obtenerCursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(cls._SELECCIONAR)
            registros = cursor.fetchall()
            personas=[]
            for registro in registros:
                persona = Persona(registro[0], registro[1], registro[2], registro[3])
                personas.append(persona)
            return personas


if __name__ == '__main__':
     personas = PersonaDao.seleccionar()
     for persona in personas:
          log.debug(persona)
```

Terminal says `AttributeError: __enter__` and it has problems with line 28 (`personas = PersonaDao.seleccionar()`) and line 17 (`with Conexion.obtenerCursor() as cursor:`).

How I can resolve it? I have to keep studying but I'm blocked.

This is the Connection class:

```
from logger_base import log
import psycopg2 as bd
import sys

class Conexion:
_DATABASE = 'test_db'
_USERNAME = 'postgres'
_PASSWORD = 'Dragui'
_DB_PORT = '5432'
_HOST = '127.0.0.1'
_conexion = None
_cursor = None

@classmethod
def obtenerConexion(cls):
    if cls._conexion is None:
        try:
            cls._conexion = bd.connect( host=cls._HOST,user=cls._USERNAME,password=cls._PASSWORD,port=cls._DB_PORT, database=cls._DATABASE)
            log.debug(f'Conexión exitosa: {cls._conexion}')
            return cls._conexion
        except Exception as e:
            log.error(f'Ocurrió una excepción al obtener la conexión: {e}')
            sys.exit()
    else:
        return cls._conexion

@classmethod
def obtenerCursor(cls):
    if cls._cursor is None:
        try:
            cls._cursor = cls.obtenerConexion().cursor()
            log.debug(f'Se abrió correctamente el cursor: {cls._cursor}')
        except Exception as e:
            log.error(f'Ocurrió una excepción al obtener el cursor: {e}')
            sys.exit()
    else:
        return cls._cursor
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Conexion.obtenerConexion()
    Conexion.obtenerCursor()
```

Comment: Is this an issue with vscode or your code? Does the code run? Generally, a context manager needs `__enter__` and `__exist__` attributes. If `Conexion.obtenerCursor` doesn't have that, you cannot use it as context manager. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/context-manager-in-python/

Comment: It means the `Conexion` class doesn't have an `__enter__()` method so cannot be used with `with` statement.

Comment: Sanky: To resolve it take out the `with` and just use `cursor = Conexion.obtenerCursor()`.

Comment: I edited the original post with my connection class. I don't know how to integrate the `__enter__` and `__exit__` method in it, please help. Also, `cursor = Conexion.obtenerCursor()` does not work, it says `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'execute'`

Comment: `obtenerCursor()` doesn't return anything on the first call - it sets `cls._cursor`, but doesn't return it.

Comment: That was it!!! Thank you a lot @jasonharper!! 
Thanks for everyone who took time for replaying me also!